# Chrome is not rendering/previewing Apple pass whereas Safari previewing the pass when I click the download link

Tags: passkit, apple-wallet, pkpass

I created Apple passes file and uploaded to my web server. I have **Pkpass** files under my web server folders. I am hosting them under IIS.

- I have added "`application/vnd.apple.pkpass`" MIME type on IIS.
- I am hosting it under a **subdomain** (not an IP address) with **HTTPS** (with a valid up-to-date SSL certificate)

When I access the Pkpass files on my iPhone with **Safari** browser everything is working smoothly. The pass is previewing and add button appears.

However, when I access it with the **Chrome** browser, it is not being previewed, just downloaded the file to the download folder.
Any idea will be appreciated to work correctly on Chrome?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: @Nightwolf You can check my own below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding mime type to the file definition on a GET controller.

```
    var mimeType = "application/vnd.apple.pkpass";
    var fileBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);

    return File(fileBytes, mimeType, fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you. I resurrected an old bug on Chromium and as of Chrome 119 this is fixed. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1349154#c7